# which is lightest linux distro to install utility softwares in vm environment?

Tags: linux, distro

My application is running on ubuntu 14.04 vms. And it is decided that we install utility software like security Gateway , imq on individual vms.

I think it is overkill to run a security gateway on full fledged OS. Is there any better way, wherein i can use a OS with lightest memory, filesystem and cpu footprint ?

Just as some applications can get their work done using lighttpd in-place of a complete webServer.

Comment: well , i have installed security gateway on  ubuntu 14.04 server vm . The vm occupies 1.8 G. I think there might be a better way. Also i am not allowed to used container as my host and guest can be of different falvors

Comment: you could try Lubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I am need of a lightweight server image, which will be easier to store as well . Lubuntu takes 800+ MB.
I think https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD will do.
Let me try that and post the results.